# How do I move the apply coupon input below the order on the checkout page in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, css, woocommerce

On the woocommerce checkout page I want to move the field where the apply coupon input is and place it just below the order summary and above the payment options. I'm not sure how to change the php because the checkout page is comprised of multiple php files therefore I come to you genius people to help. Anybody know how I can achieve this? Thank you in advance!
P.S. I've added pictures; the first is of the top half of the page and the second is of the second half of the page.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide us with a link to your site so that we can have a look at the structure? - if your site has some sort of "contstruction" mode enabled, then perhaps a screenshot of what you are seeing?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using a localhost to build the site at the moment. Would you like some screen shot photos? @Frits

Comment: Ah, that is unfortunate. Yes, a screenshot would be the next best thing :)

Comment: @Frits there you go :)

Answer (score 11):

If you are comfortable editing your functions.php file inside your theme directory, then you can add the following lines of code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form' );
```

This will essentially remove the coupon (which is hooked before the checkout form) and re-add it AFTER the checkout form.

Alternatively, you can use Javascript to "cut&paste" the html block containing the coupon fields, but this is a messy way of coding and I would not suggest taking that route.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked thank you. What is does is add the coupon input below the payment options as well. Do you know how I can add it above the payment options?

Comment: Just fixed it! Thanks @Frits

Answer (score 10):

@noufalcep you answer is not clear.

Finally after everything i came up with a working solution. i am using woocommerce 3.2.5 and wordpress version of 4.8.3.

As @noufalcep said the form inside form is not the issue. When we do

> add_action( ‘woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review’, ‘woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form’ );

coupon container doesn't wrap up with form element. But the button has submit as input type. That's why when we apply coupon main form get suibmitted.

Therefore what i did is inserted the coupon form with jquery insertAfter. Below is the code. It is perfectly working.

```
 var coupon = $(".checkout_coupon");
 coupon.insertAfter('.shop_table.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table');
```

Then this will add the form after review order table. if you want it with "Have a coupon? Click here to enter your code" text, you have to wrap the element with the form.

A working example can be seen here, 
https://themovementfix.com/checkout/

Comment: is this code is working for you ?? i have tested but its not working for me could you please provide the full code for me ??

Comment: yeah, it works. Just go to the above link and test it. are you writing this within ready event?

Comment: Your code is working for me thank you for your code Very nice, thank you. This should be the selected answer. I am going to do Up Vote

Answer (score 6):

This worked great for me:

Add this jQuery:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        var coupon2 = $(".checkout_coupon.woocommerce-form-coupon");
        coupon2.insertAfter('.shop_table.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table');
    })
})
(jQuery);
```

Add this css:

```
/*unhide copuon code checkout*/
.checkout_coupon {
 display: block !important;
}
/*hide message have a coupon?*/
.woocommerce-info {
display:none;
}
/*coupon code checkout style*/
.checkout_coupon button.button{
background-color: #insert button color here;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This how I put the coupon form after the billing total. So it would be more helpful to use while customization.
Just place this code inside your functions.php and see the customization on the frontend.

```
    /*
     * Removing default "Coupon form" from the top of the checkout page
     */
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );

    /*
     * Hooking "Coupon form" after order total in checkout page with custom function
     */
    add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );

    /*
     * Rendering html for "Coupon form" with custom function
     */
    function woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom() {
        echo '<tr class="coupon-form"><td colspan="2">';
        wc_get_template(
            'checkout/form-coupon.php',
            array(
                'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
            )
        );
        echo '</td></tr>';
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

After reading about the form within a form issue that stops the usual add_actions from working, it inspired me to create a **form-checkout.php** file in my theme’s woocommerce folder, and simply move the order review's starting `< form ... >` code to right after the `do_action( ‘woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details’ );` line, then used these two lines to move the coupon form down to under the Your Order review display, and it worked great in v3.0.x of WooCommerce:

```
remove_action( ‘woocommerce_before_checkout_form’, ‘woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form’, 10 );

add_action( ‘woocommerce_checkout_after_order_review’, ‘woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form’ );
```

Without moving the starting form code, it wouldn’t work due to the form within a form issue mentioned, but once moved, works easily.

Answer (score 2):

As of woocommerce 2.6 (or maybe even earlier) placing it "after order review" no longer works. If you apply a coupon it will place the order automatically. It's caused by the form within a form issue.

In Woocommerce 2.6, using hooks alone, only these 2 options currently work:

option 1:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
```

option 2:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the whole checkout page is inside a form, and the coupon is a form also. And you are unable to nest two forms. So even though you could technically move the coupon form above the review order section, it won't work properly. You need to rearrange your form and split them into two to make it work.

Answer (score -1):

**Move WooCommerce Coupon Field in Checkout Page** 
Using process: You can use the code using any plugin like (Code snippets) or function.PHP

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_cart_contents', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom' );
function woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form_custom() {
    echo '<tr class="coupon-form"><td colspan="2">';
    
    wc_get_template(
        'checkout/form-coupon.php',
        array(
            'checkout' => WC()->checkout(),
        )
    );
    echo '</tr></td>';
}
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: You can use the code using any plugin like (Code snippets) or function.PHP

Answer (score -2):

A slight revision on a suggested answer:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'woocommerce_checkout_coupon_form');
```

This places the coupon input below the order and above the payment options.

Comment: Have you tried this? Didn't work for me. Can't move the coupon within the checkout form. It will submit the checkout instead of adding the coupon.