# WooCommerce 5.6.0 Checkout Coupon Form Issue using functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

My original coupon box was set by default to the top.

I'm using [How do I move the apply coupon input below the order on the checkout page in Woocommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66754870/11987538) answer code and moved the box below products in the "my order" section.

Each time I submit a coupon, it removes some of the entered data as the page is being submitted.

Is there a method to remove this submit page feature & have it behave like the default option where it updates without refreshing the page?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this answer (jquery part) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161794/how-do-i-move-the-apply-coupon-input-below-the-order-on-the-checkout-page-in-woo

Comment: @MartinMirchev this unfortunately, does not fix this issue. Adding the two lines of jQuery has no effect on this issue.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53443380/11987538). However, please be aware that Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutoring service. Pure code-writing requests and/or recommendations are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to show [what you have tried so far to solve your problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).